# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError uploading big files

Tags: java, glassfish

**Before Nick Wilson answer:**

I'm developing a Java EE 6 web application under Glassfish 3. The main characteristic is to be able to upload big files (1Gb ore more bigger). When I try to upload a file (400MB of size) I receive the **java.lang.OutOfMemoryError** exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
at java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:272)
at com.google.common.io.ByteStreams.read(ByteStreams.java:899)
at com.google.common.io.ByteStreams.readFully(ByteStreams.java:733)
at com.google.common.io.ByteStreams.readFully(ByteStreams.java:714)
at org.richfaces.request.BaseUploadedFile.getData(BaseUploadedFile.java:68)
at EJB.FileUploadBean.listener(FileUploadBean.java:147)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:254)
at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:302)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
at org.richfaces.event.MethodExpressionEventListener.processEvent(MethodExpressionEventListener.java:125)
```

I already incremented the memory in Glassfish JVM Options:

```
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-XX:PermSize=128m
-XX:NewRatio=2
-XX:+UseParallelGC
-Xmx2048m
```

I tried the following code to upload file, but both give me the same error:

```
InputStream filecontent = null;
    int read = 0;
    final byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

    OutputStream fop = null;
    File fout;
    if (file.getLength() > 0) {
        try {
            fout = new File(filename);
            fop = new FileOutputStream(fout);
            filecontent = item.getInputStream();
            if (!fout.exists()) {
                fout.createNewFile();
            }
            while ((read = filecontent.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                 fop.write(bytes, 0, read);
            }
```

and

```
 FileOutputStream fop = null;
    File fout;
    if (file.getLength() > 0) {
        try {
            fout = new File(filename);
            fop = new FileOutputStream(fout);

            if (!fout.exists()) {
                fout.createNewFile();
            }
            fop.write(item.getData());
            fop.flush();
            fop.close();
```

How can I solve the problem?

THanks

**After Nick Wilson answer**

I changed my code to:

```
public void listener(FileUploadEvent event) throws Exception {
    ufile = new UploadFile();
    InputStream filecontent = null;
    UploadedFile item = event.getUploadedFile();
    if (item instanceof UploadedFile25) {
        filecontent = ((UploadedFile25) item).getInputStream();
    } else {

        filecontent = item.getInputStream();
    }
    UploadedText file = new UploadedText();
    file.setLength(item.getData().length);
    file.setName(item.getName());
    Date date = new Date();
    String epoch = fDir + String.valueOf(date.getTime());
    File fPath = new File(epoch);
    fPath.mkdir();

    //file.setData(item.getData());
    files.add(file);
    String filename = epoch + '/' + item.getName();

    int read = 0;
    final byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

    OutputStream fop = null;
    File fout;
    if (file.getLength() > 0) {
        try {
            fout = new File(filename);
            fop = new FileOutputStream(fout);

            if (!fout.exists()) {
                fout.createNewFile();
            }
            while ((read = filecontent.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                fop.write(bytes, 0, read);
            }
```

But I receive the same exception.

to be able to upload big files (1Gb ore more bigger). When I try to upload a file (400MB of size) I receive the **java.lang.OutOfMemoryError** exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
at java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:272)
at com.google.common.io.ByteStreams.read(ByteStreams.java:899)
at com.google.common.io.ByteStreams.readFully(ByteStreams.java:733)
at com.google.common.io.ByteStreams.readFully(ByteStreams.java:714)
at org.richfaces.request.BaseUploadedFile.getData(BaseUploadedFile.java:68)
at EJB.FileUploadBean.listener(FileUploadBean.java:147)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:254)
at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:302)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
at org.richfaces.event.MethodExpressionEventListener.processEvent(MethodExpressionEventListener.java:125)
```

I already incremented the memory in Glassfish JVM Options:

```
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-XX:PermSize=128m
-XX:NewRatio=2
-XX:+UseParallelGC
-Xmx2048m
```

I tried the following code to upload file, but both give me the same error:

```
InputStream filecontent = null;
    int read = 0;
    final byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

    OutputStream fop = null;
    File fout;
    if (file.getLength() > 0) {
        try {
            fout = new File(filename);
            fop = new FileOutputStream(fout);
            filecontent = item.getInputStream();
            if (!fout.exists()) {
                fout.createNewFile();
            }
            while ((read = filecontent.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                 fop.write(bytes, 0, read);
            }
```

and

```
 FileOutputStream fop = null;
    File fout;
    if (file.getLength() > 0) {
        try {
            fout = new File(filename);
            fop = new FileOutputStream(fout);

            if (!fout.exists()) {
                fout.createNewFile();
            }
            fop.write(item.getData());
            fop.flush();
            fop.close();
```

How can I solve the problem?

THanks

**After Nick Wilson answer**

I changed my code to:

```
public void listener(FileUploadEvent event) throws Exception {
    ufile = new UploadFile();
    InputStream filecontent = null;
    UploadedFile item = event.getUploadedFile();
    if (item instanceof UploadedFile25) {
        filecontent = ((UploadedFile25) item).getInputStream();
    } else {

        filecontent = item.getInputStream();
    }
    UploadedText file = new UploadedText();
    file.setLength(item.getData().length);
    file.setName(item.getName());
    Date date = new Date();
    String epoch = fDir + String.valueOf(date.getTime());
    File fPath = new File(epoch);
    fPath.mkdir();

    //file.setData(item.getData());
    files.add(file);
    String filename = epoch + '/' + item.getName();

    int read = 0;
    final byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

    OutputStream fop = null;
    File fout;
    if (file.getLength() > 0) {
        try {
            fout = new File(filename);
            fop = new FileOutputStream(fout);

            if (!fout.exists()) {
                fout.createNewFile();
            }
            while ((read = filecontent.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                fop.write(bytes, 0, read);
            }
```

But I receive the same exception.

```
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
at java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:272)
at com.google.common.io.ByteStreams.read(ByteStreams.java:899)
at com.google.common.io.ByteStreams.readFully(ByteStreams.java:733)
at com.google.common.io.ByteStreams.readFully(ByteStreams.java:714)
at org.richfaces.request.BaseUploadedFile.getData(BaseUploadedFile.java:68)
at EJB.FileUploadBean.listener(FileUploadBean.java:157)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:254)
at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:302)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
at org.richfaces.event.MethodExpressionEventListener.processEvent(MethodExpressionEventListener.java:125)
... 38 more
```

I don't know how to solve :-(

Comment: Did you try increasing your heap size for JVM even further: -Xms and -Xmx.

Look into not loading our files into a byte array but rather try just reading from a stream into another stream directly.

Comment: Are you using the Servlet 3 upload specs? What is your `@MultipartConfig` configuration? If this is configured correctly, I believe you will not have to resort to the (unscalable) solutions involving increasing heap size.

Comment: Your problem seems to be in calling `BaseUploadedFile.getData`. This causes RichFaces to load the whole file into memory. For large files you're better making sure it streams all the way through. Changing memory settings isn't a good fix.

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos I gave it from Oracle documentation: @MultipartConfig(location="/tmp", fileSizeThreshold=1024*1024, 
    maxFileSize=1024*1024*5, maxRequestSize=1024*1024*5*5)

Comment: @NickWilson I use RichFaces, so how can be sure to streams all? Where I've to search?

Comment: Is `item` an instance of [UploadFile25](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_3_X/javadoc/richfaces-components-ui/org/richfaces/request/UploadedFile25.html)? If so, it should have a `getInputStream` method.

Comment: @NickWilson Good observation. I think you should post your comments as an answer.

Comment: @NickWilson  public void listener(FileUploadEvent event) throws Exception {
        ufile = new UploadFile();
        UploadedFile item = event.getUploadedFile();
        UploadedText file = new UploadedText();
        file.setLength(item.getData().length);
        file.setName(item.getName());

Comment: @NickWilson is an instance of UploadFile, and lie you see in the posted code I used getInputStream receiving the same error.

Comment: The code you posted above still has an `item.getData` call which causes the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to stream the data from the uploaded file rather than calling `getData`:

```
 public void listener(FileUploadEvent event) throws Exception {
 UploadedFile item = event.getUploadedFile();
 InputStream is = item.getInputStream();
 .....
```

Calls to `item.getData()` will cause the whole file to be loaded into memory.

Comment: I changed the code as you can see in my question, but nothing changed.

Comment: The posted code has `file.setLength(item.getData().length);`, which will still load the whole file into memory. UploadedFile has a `getSize()` method on it, try that instead.

Comment: Yeah!!!! This seems to solve the problem. You are great! :-)) Now there is another strange thing, the file is written in /opt where I've installed glassfish and not in the directory where I want. Glassfish store temporarely the file in its home?

Comment: Ok, I solve the last problem. I have to set org.richfaces.fileUpload.createTempFiles parameter to false in web.xml. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that you have given the JVM appropriate heap size, check your config and make sure that -Xms is set to say 512 but the -Xmx value is much larger than the file size, particularly if you are loading the whole file into memory.